# PHP Javascript - keep localStorage on PHP session_destroy

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage, session-cookies

I have a strange (for me) behavior about use of PHP `session_destroy()`, used for logout, and JS `localStorage` used for avoid continuous DB ajax request.

**So. My current (and working) scenario:**

1. At login form, PHP do a `session_start()` -> browser writes cookies with `PHPSESSID` (*no `localStorage` at moment*);
2. After logon, IF `localStorage.getItem('myDataItem') === null`, data are requested once (ajax) and written with `localStorage.setItem('myDataItem', 'Hi, I'm your ajax response')`. If `localStorage.getItem('myDataItem') !== null` do noting;

Code:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('myDataItem') === null){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php', 
        type:'post', 
        data:{request: 'dbInfo'}
     }).done(function(jsonObjectResponse){
            localStorage.setItem('myDataItem', JSON.stringify(jsonObjectResponse))
     });
}
```

3. On logout click element, browser runs a function with an ajax request that do a PHP's `session_destroy()` and do a JS `location.reload()` 
   and restart from the login form;

Code:

```
$("#logout_element").on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php', 
        type:'post', 
        data:{request: 'logout'} /*ajax PHP do a session_destroy()*/
     })
    .done(function(){
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

So far, everything (F5/refresh) is regular, if it were not for the logout/`session_destroy ()`, the localStorage disappears

---

**My Goal**

keep localStorage even after the `session_destroy ()`

Best,

Oscar

Comment: Are you sure you pass that condition ? `(localStorage.getItem('myDataItem') === null`

Comment: Try: `localStorage.getItem('myDataItem') === undefined` as this is JavaScript rather than PHP.

Comment: @CD001 According to the docs, `getItem()` returns `null` if the key is not found (I just tried it in the console and can confirm): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem

Comment: PHP has no effect on your client's storage (but I guess you already knew that)... there might be something else at play. `localStorage` is bound to domains; are your pages all served from the same origin? Maybe try debugging the contents of `localStorage` before and after you call `location.reload()`? (make sure you check the option to preserve the log between page loads)

Comment: @MátéSafranka 
ok, Chrome had cheated me. I checked to the left of the address bar, in the cookie window, and I realized that the localStorage appeared only with the login. And only now, after your answer, I did a check in the debug console, and the localStorage object also remains with the logout.I made a pretty bad!!! This is really embarrassing. It was all right. I only looked in the wrong place. Thanks for your support and sorry :(

Comment: No need to apologize, this kind of thing happens to all of us at some point :)